# delete heading tag inside custom field with regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a [custom field](https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/) called `description` that stores a text like this:

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
```

I need to delete the heading inside (`<h2.*?<\/h2>`) only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$removed = preg_replace( "/<h2.*?<\/h2>/", "<h2><\/h2>", $original );
```

This will remove the text in the tag. Replace with an empty string to remove it altogether.

Comment: Regex should not be used on valud html.  This question is a mega-duplicate which should br closed instead of answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use substr to cut it into two parts. One till `<h2>` and the other part beginning from `</h2>`. You can get the index of the beginning of these tags with `strpos`.

```
$string = '<h2>This is a heading</h2> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo';

$new_string1 = substr($string, 0, (strpos($string, '<h2>')+4)); 
$new_string2 = substr($string, strpos($string, '</h2>'));  

//Will output: <h2></h2> Lorem ipsum ...
echo $new_string1 . $new_string2;
```